# My session is not getting cleared even if I am entering a new JSP session

Tags: javascript, jsp, session

I have a onload function:

```
function fnload(){

    if(document.getElementById("a").value!=null){
    document.getElementById("txtDepName").value=document.getElementById("a").value;
    document.getElementById("txtempNum").value=document.getElementById("c").value;

    document.getElementById("txtempNames").value=document.getElementById("b").value;
}

document.getElementById("leavename").value ="--Select--";

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var day = currentDate.getDate();
    var month = currentDate.getMonth()+1;

    var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var appleddate=day + "/" + month + "/" + year ;
    document.getElementById("txApplieddate").value =appleddate;
    document.getElementById("noofdays").value =1;

}
```

in my body I am giving:

```
<input type="hidden" id="a" value="<%=session.getAttribute("Emp_Name")%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="b" value="<%=session.getAttribute("Department")%>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="c" value="<%=session.getAttribute("Emp_no")%>"/>
```

but even if I am checking null every time its getting previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will work.

```
session.removeAttribute("paramName");
```